# Preset/default value filter of google visualization library facets dive

Tags: visualization, facet

I'm facing a slightly problem using the facets dive visualization (more information here : https://github.com/PAIR-code/facets/tree/master/facets_dive)

In fact, I want (to place it on a streamlit app) to preset some filter at specific column of my dataset.

But can't find how to do it. There is an explanation in the readme of the github but without example of how to implement it.

Do you have some advice or have your already been in the same situation ?
Thanks